# Change of session fetching code in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Previously when I fetched session in codeigniter I used the following code:

```
$this->session->userdata('session_id');
```

But now I am facing problem this and have used this `$this->session->session_id` and getting session id.

I want to know, is this mismatach occuring due to change of version or anything else?

Comment: The latter is the newer way. They keep the former for backwards compatibility. [Reference](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are referring to is the "new" way:

```
$name = $this->session->name
```

which I think makes more sense as a it removes a layer (userdata function) between you and your data.

However, you can still do it the old way (CI has always been good about backwards compatability):

```
$name = $this->session->userdata('name');
```

OR:

Since CI 3 uses native sessions unlike CI 2 you can use the session superglobal:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
```

**All of these functions/properties/methods will yield the same result!**